# Why html shows the object returned by the computed property is ‘undefined’?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I have a error at my vue project.I use `computed` to return a object.

```
computed: {
        getOpLog() {
            if (this.product_menu) {
                this.product_menu.forEach(opLogItem => {
                    if(opLogItem.id === 'menu_item_oplog') {
                        return opLogItem;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

and my debugger shows that I have the right return object.

[image]

But when i run it in brower, it just not work.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hidden' of undefined"
```

Here is my html.

```
<el-menu-item v-if="getOpLog.hidden" :id="getOpLog.id">
...
</el-menu-item>
```

But when I use this

```
getOpLog() {
    if (this.product_menu) {
        return this.product_menu[8]
    }
}
```

It work.I want to know how can i fix this.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your **if** condition inside the getter is **false** i.e. `if (this.product_menu)`, then getter will return **undefined** object. And thus, Vue.js complains.

As a simple remedy, add an extra check in `v-if` like:

```
<el-menu-item v-if="getOpLog && getOpLog.hidden" :id="getOpLog.id">
...
</el-menu-item>
```

Further, using return inside the `forEach` function of an array doesn't really cause a return from actual getter function. It is just returning from the inner arrow function. You will need to modify your code using `Array.prototype.find` method:

```
computed: {
    getOpLog() {
        if (this.product_menu) {
            const item = this.product_menu.find(opLogItem => {
                return opLogItem.id === 'menu_item_oplog';
            });

            return item;
        }
    }
};
```

But, you still should have v-if check for `getOpLog` in case `find` method returns `undefined` value.

Comment: At this way, ```getOpLog``` is always undefined, and the ```el-menu-item``` is never show

Comment: Yes, that's the way it is going to be. But if you have `getOpLog` as `undefined`, then you can also use Vue.js `v-else` directive to show alternate content/component.

Comment: That is not what I mean.My point is that  ```getOpLog``` is required to return an object which is correct at the js, but not at html.I want to figure this out.

Comment: @suedar, I read your code again and modified my answer accordingly. This should work for you. Use `find` method instead of `forEach`.

Comment: I am not really sure why. Try putting debugger/console.log before `return item;`